# How to test run block of a module

Tags: angularjs

I want my AngularJS app to make a http request to retrieve user information from the server or redirect to login screen. I implemented this in a run block of my app's main module. But how do I test the code in a run block? Or should I move this initialization code in a controller to make it testable? I'm writing my tests with Karma and Jasmine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the reference to the run block via the _runBlocks property of the module.

The file with your module code:

```
angular.module('xmpl', []).
  run(function() {
    // some code here
  });
```

The test suite:

```
var myModule = angular.module('xmpl'),
    runBlock = myModule._runBlocks[0];
// Now can test the runBlock function according to your scenario
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But in my case, as I defined my run block like this: angular.module('app', []).run(['dep', function(dep) { ... }]); I had to access the actual run block function as angular.module('app')._runBlocks[0][1]

Comment: One helpful note is that you can use `$injector.invoke` to inject dependencies into the run block.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to move the code in the run block into a service:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function(runBlockService) {
    runBlockService.run();
  });
```

and write unit tests for that service.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out the $routeProvider resolve property? you can use the resolve property to check on the user's logged in status and act accordingly. see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ and [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider#when](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)

in the resolve object, you can include the name of a service and/or factory that needs to be resolved (and therefore have separate unit tests for the service/factory), or if the logic is simple enough and doesn't need to be broken out in its own service, you can just write a new function

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This would be great if I wanted to check the session on every route change, but because I want to do it only when first entering my app, I'll rely on a run block.