# Error: Angularjs factory is not defined in Jasmine spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, factory

I'm working with Jasmine to do tests on my angular app.
I'm am trying to test a function called `calculateAverageAge` which is defined in an angular factory called `sharedFactory` and it is telling me that `sharedFactory` is undefined.

```
ReferenceError: sharedFactory is not defined
```

I've included all the src files. Is there anything I'm missing?
Note: it's working in the actual app but not in the spec. Thanks

## Jasmine suite

```
describe("SharedFactory", function () { 
    
    it("should calcuate the average age from an array of ages", function () { 
        var ageArray = [1,6,9,23,33,62,63,4,5];
        var averageAge =  sharedFactory.calculateAverageAge(ageArray);

                
        expect(averageAge).not.toBeLessThan(1); 
        expect(averageAge).not.toBeGreaterThan(120); 

    }); 
   

});
```

SharedFactory.js

```
agesApp.factory('sharedFactory', function($http, loginFactory) {

    return {
            calculateAverageAge: function(ageArray){
                var sumOfAges = 0;
                var numberofAges = ageArray.length;
                ageArray.forEach(function(age) {
                    sumOfAges += age;
                        
                    }); 
                var averageAge = sumOfAges/numberofAges;
                return averageAge;
            }
            

    };
});
```

SpecRunner.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.6.1</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.6.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.6.1/jasmine.css">

<script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.6.1/boot.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>


<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="../modules/agesApp.js"></script>
<script src="../factories/loginFactory.js"></script>
<script src="../factories/sharedFactory.js"></script>

<!-- include spec files here... -->
<script src="spec/SharedFactorySpec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't shown which modules are loaded in tests (`module(...)` call). It's likely that you haven't load it at all. Having JS files loaded is not enough, we would never want to load all registered modules automatically in tests.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually my first time to use jasmine with angular. I havent loaded any modules within the test (just the js files). I've seen this post which uses beforeEach. Do you suggest I do something similar to this? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249933/globally-injecting-am-angularjs-factory-mockup-when-testing-with-jasmine ...

Comment: The post explains how services can be mocked with `module`, which is not exactly your case. I guess you haven't used ngMock at all, which is highly desirable in Angular unit tests. angular-mocks.js should be loaded with other Angular files. I would suggest to check a guide https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing for starters.

Comment: @estus Ok great thanks a lot. I will :)